# Adding Recaptcha Token to Request in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, http-post, token, recaptcha

So I'm using the Node.JS Request Module and I wish to put the recaptcha token (thats generated once solved) inside my request, while I'm unsure how I implement such.

This is currently my code, and while I've tried a form, it still wouldn't.

```
function fireVote(username, captchaKey){
    rp({
        uri: voteUrl,
        method: "POST",
        qs: {
            "username": username,
            "g-recaptcha-response": captchaKey
        },
        headers: {
            'User-Agent': "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:47.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/47.0"
        }
    }).then(body => {
        console.log(body);
        if(body.includes("Voted")){
            console.log("Done!");
        }
    })
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You have to send the values in the request body, 
in the format that the content type specifies.

Usually, the content type is application/x-www-form-urlencoded

Follow according to the Request documentation how to send POST request

https://www.npmjs.com/package/request

```
function fireVote(username, captchaKey){

    request.post({
    url:voteUrl, 
    form: {
                "username": username,
                "g-recaptcha-response": captchaKey

    }}, 
    function(err,httpResponse,body){ 
        console.log(body);
    })
}
```

Actually, there is no need to send the token if you not gone verify reCAPTCHA on server side.

> https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify

Comment: Weird after implementing it, seems to think the captcha hasn't been solved.

Comment: Captcha is valid for a time defined

Comment: How long is that? Sorry

Comment: There more than one rule to declare if it is valid https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA

Comment: Oh right damn, what would be the best way to do so? I have the token from the service, its just putting in via the request above where it'll work..

Comment: I saw that, issue is its for creating your own captcha rather than solve it.